# Is that possible to change the custom setting "visibility" from protected to public once after it is created?

Tags: customsetting

i have created a custom setting with visibility as protected. And now i want it to make the visibility to public. But when i edit the custom setting the visibility option is greyed out.

How could i change it to public?

Do i need to delete the current custom setting and create a new one with the public visibility?

What would if i have lot of data stored in custom setting and at a later stage want it to change to public?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't change the visibility once set. If you need to change it, you must create a new custom setting. If you need to retain the data, you will need to copy the data. If this in a managed package, you can set an install handler script up migrate the data. If it is not a managed package, this setting has no effect, and there is no reason to change the visibility.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I need to delete the current one and going to create a new one.